# Ignoring certain values when calculating AVG sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query which finds all the hotels with overall rating greater than 3 and average cleanliness greater or equal to 5. There are 2 tables - Reviews where there is the [Cleanliness] attribute and Hotel - where there is the [Overall_Rating] attribute and both tables have [Hotel_ID] as an attribute.

```
SELECT
    Reviews.Hotel_ID
FROM [Reviews]
INNER JOIN [Hotel]
    ON Reviews.Hotel_ID = Hotel.Hotel_ID
WHERE [Overall_Rating] > 3
GROUP BY Reviews.Hotel_ID
HAVING AVG([Cleanliness]) >= 5;
```

The problem is in some of the reviews the Cleanliness value is -1 and if this is the case I need to ignore it when calculating the average. I came up with:

```
SELECT
    Reviews.Hotel_ID
FROM [Reviews]
INNER JOIN [Hotel]
    ON Reviews.Hotel_ID = Hotel.Hotel_ID AND
       Reviews.Cleanliness > -1
WHERE [Overall_Rating] > 3
GROUP BY Reviews.Hotel_ID
HAVING AVG([Cleanliness]) >= 5;
```

Is this correct and if not how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering with WHERE is done before the aggregation, with HAVING, afterwards. So you should put the `Cleanliness > -1` into the WHERE clause.

Putting it into the ON clause of the join works exactly the same way, but makes the query a little bit more unclear because this filter does not actually have anything to do with the join itself.